# Tensorflow tokeniser: the maximum number of words to keep

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tokenize

Trying to tokenize the IMDB movie reviews by applying Tensorflow tokenizer.  I want to have a maximum 10000-word vocabulary. For unseen words, I use a default token.

```
type(X), X.shape, X[:3]

(pandas.core.series.Series,(25000,),
 0    first think another disney movie might good it...
 1    put aside dr house repeat missed desperate hou...
 2    big fan stephen king s work film made even gre...
 Name: SentimentText, dtype: object)

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

tokenizer=Tokenizer(num_words=10000,oov_token='xxxxxxx')
# fit on the input data 
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
```

When I check the number of words in tokenizer dictionary I get:

```
X_dict=tokenizer.word_index

list(enumerate(X_dict.items()))[:10]
[(0, ('xxxxxxx', 1)),
 (1, ('s', 2)),
 (2, ('movie', 3)),
 (3, ('film', 4)),
 (4, ('not', 5)),
 (5, ('it', 6)),
 (6, ('one', 7)),
 (7, ('like', 8)),
 (8, ('i', 9)),
 (9, ('good', 10))]

print(len(X_dict))

Out: 74120
```

Why do I get 74120 words instead of 10000 words?

Answer (score 1):

Because the dictionary of words is always saved. When you have a look at the source [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py) you see that in the function `fit_on_texts()` the parameter `num_words` is ignored. However, when you convert your text to sequences with `texts_to_sequences()` you can see the call to the `texts_to_sequences_generator()` which then has the following piece of code:

```
for w in seq:
    i = self.word_index.get(w)
    if i is not None:
         if num_words and i >= num_words:
              if oov_token_index is not None:
                  vect.append(oov_token_index)
              else:
                  vect.append(i)
         elif self.oov_token is not None:
            vect.append(oov_token_index)
    yield vect
```

There you can see, that num_words is noticed and used for further generating the sequences. This is useful as you can change the number of words easily without fitting on the whole text again, so experiment whether it suits your needs well or you need more words for successfully work on your task, as nicolewhite states in her github [answer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8092#issuecomment-335559116).

So basically, what you observe is just as expected, when you run `np.unique()` on all of your sequences, you will not have more than 10000 values.

Comment: From Temsorflow doc on Tokenizer:  <qoute>   num_words: the maximum number of words to keep, based
        on word frequency. Only the most common `num_words-1` words will
        be kept.
</quote> Why provide parameter documentation (`num_words`) that does not correspond to the way it works? This is very misleading.

Comment: You could open a Github issue, asking whether this description is correct or not. However, I find it pretty useful as you do not have to fit on your text each time for different max_words, which would else be a hard pain. It is indeed misleading, that you get  >74k by `print(len(X_dict))`, but I think its a good deal taking this than having to fit the text each time again with differrent num_words parameters, which can take alot of time, depending on the size of your text and as this is a common hyper parameter, you just dont want to spend time on that